# Issues writing list/array like columns in pandas based on JSON API data to SQL

Tags: python, sql, json, pandas, api

I'm facing issues uploading panda dfs with sqlalchemy. The issues arises when I try to write dfs with columns having list like features as depicted below:

[image]

The data that I write is based on JSON API data being converted to dataframes using pd.DataFrame.

The uploading is done using pandas.to_sql.

I can easily write the data if I omit the data with the list/array type feature. Any suggestions?

Comment: [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the list and then store the df in in SQL

Comment: Hmm. Good suggestion. However, I get an AttributeError: "DataFrame" has no attribute to 'explode'.

Comment: `explode` works only for pandas version `0.25` and above. For versions lower than this, you have to write a few lines on code. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939) are some ways to do it. I would update pandas but whatever suits you better  :)

Comment: It's not really what I'm looking for. Ideally I would want to write the data exactly as is. Thus, I would want SQL to accept the depicted format above or manipulate the format such that SQL will accept it.